# Setting State Between Radio Buttons

Tags: reactjs

An example of the issue is found on [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-bush-zgtvms). Am I short circuiting myself between TRUE/FALSE values?

Can someone please help explain why the state variable `isOptionOne` is not being set as expected? Upon calling `setIsOptionOne` I would think that I can use `isOptionOne` in the remaining lines of code of the function. Unfortunately, that does not seem to be the case. To verify, see the `console.log` output. The two values for `isDefault` and `isOptionOne` should match.

Where am I going wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the expected behavior. React batches the state updates, which means it doesn't immediately update the state and re-render everything after each `setState` method call. From [official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html):

> `setState`() enqueues changes to the component state and tells React
> that this component and its children need to be re-rendered with the
> updated state. This is the primary method you use to update the user
> interface in response to event handlers and server responses.
>
> Think of `setState`() as a request rather than an immediate command to
> update the component. For better perceived performance, React may
> delay it, and then update several components in a single pass. React
> does not guarantee that the state changes are applied immediately.
>
> `setState`() does not always immediately update the component. It may
> batch or defer the update until later. This makes reading `this.state`
> right after calling `setState`() a potential pitfall. Instead, use
> `componentDidUpdate` or a `setState` callback (`setState(updater, callback)`), either of which are guaranteed to fire after the update
> has been applied. If you need to set the state based on the previous
> state, read about the updater argument below.

Additionally, the above document is for the traditional class component's `setState` API. If you want to detect a change in your hook-based state, use `useEffect`.