# React Native state is not updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm coding a ToDo app in React Native, and I have the followind function

```
  const [task, setTask] = useState();
  const [taskItems, setTaskItems] = useState([]);

  const handleAddTask = () => {
    if (task !== null && task !== " " && task !== "") {
      Keyboard.dismiss();
      console.log(taskItems);
      setTaskItems([...taskItems, task])
      console.log(taskItems);
      setTask(null);
      
      storeData(taskItems.toString());
    }
  }
```

Both console.logs return the same thing, as if the state is not changin at all!

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71255827/3930247